# Alterar a pasta de dependências do projeto (lib)

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

Ao compilar meu projeto no `Netbeans` é gerado os arquivos dessa forma:

```
./dist
./dist/meuProjeto.jar
./dist/readme.txt
./dist/lib
./dist/lib/dependencia1.jar
./dist/lib/dependencia2.jar
```

E eu quero que seja gerado sem a pasta `lib`, dessa forma:

```
./dist
./dist/meuProjeto.jar
./dist/readme.txt
./dist/dependencia1.jar
./dist/dependencia2.jar
```

Sei que tem alterar o `build.xml`, mas não encontrei nada que se referia em como alterar o destino dos `.jar` dependentes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir o resultado desejado tive que fazer dois ajustes.

**1º** No arquivo `meuProjeto\nbproject\build-impl.xml` ajustei a linha:

```xml
<globmapper from="*" to="lib/*"/>
```

Para:

```xml
<globmapper from="*" to="*"/>
```

Essa linha tem como finalidade definir o caminho de onde estão os `.jar` dependentes, em relação ao `.jar` sendo executado. Esse caminho é gerado por esse script e fica no `manifest.mf` que é salvo dentro do `.jar` compilado.

**2º** No arquivo `meuProjeto\build.xml` adicionei as linhas:

```xml
<target name="-post-jar">
    <echo message="Copiando as bibliotecas dependentes para o mesmo diretório do jar"/>
    <copy todir="${dist.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${dist.dir}\lib"/>
    </copy>
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}\lib"/>
</target>
```

**PS:** Lembrando que está solução é extremamente dependente da IDE usada, neste caso o NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

acredito que você esteja procurando fazer algo do tipo "Big Jar", empacotando todas as dependências dentro de um único arquivo .jar

Para isto você deve utilizar o "Ant".

No Netbeans, abra o arquivo build.xml e deixa a tag "project" como esta abaixo substituindo "NOME_DO_SEU_JAR" pelo nome do jar desejado:

```
<project name="NOME_DO_SEU_JAR" default="default" basedir=".">
<description>DESCRICAO_DO_SEU_PROJETO</description>
<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <target name="-post-jar">  


    <property name="store.jar.name" value="NOME_DO_SEU_JAR"/>  

    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>  
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>  

    <echo message="Packaging ${store.jar.name} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>  

    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>  
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>  

    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">  
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>  
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>  

        <manifest>  
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>                  
        </manifest>  
    </jar>  

    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">  
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"  
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>  
    </zip>  

    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>  

</target>
```

Comment: Minha intenção não é gerar somente um `.jar`, mas gerar o `.jar` e suas bibliotecas de dependência na mesma pasta.

Comment: @Gleison       Já pensei em fazer isto também, mas tive muitos problemas na hora de acessar os [.jar] de dependência, você ira perceber isto caso trabalhe com arquivos. Para fazer exatamente o que você deseja não consegui uma solução. espero ter ajudado de alguma forma. Abraço.