# Como criar um executável no java + banco de dados MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jar

Criei uma aplicação java desktop que se conecta a um banco de dados MySQL, como posso gerar esta aplicação para que rode em qualquer máquina juntamente com o meu banco de dados? Obrigado!

Comment: O banco de dados é um só em algum lugar da internet ou ele deve ser instalado na máquina local junto com a aplicação?

Comment: Tem que ir na máquina local, provisoriamente eu fiz uma forma de instalar o banco, mas vou utilizar SQLite na minha aplicação para facilitar a instalação.

Answer (score 1):

1. Primeiro você precisa empacotar o seu projeto incluindo todas as sias dependências, recomento que pesquise um poco mais sobre **ANT** e **Big jar**. Para o netbeans [AQUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56618/alterar-a-pasta-de-depend%C3%AAncias-do-projeto-lib/56632#56632) tem um exemplo de como fazer compilar o seu projeto com todas as suas dependências.
2. Você pode utilizar alguns instalador como o **Inno Setup** ou **Install Creator** para juntar o instalador do **My SQL** e a sua aplicação em um único executável para distribuir.

Answer (score 0):

Tem que ser IP's ou DNS(nameserver) de conexão fixos e no driver do JBDC conecta-los corretamente com estes dados. Creio que se estiverem corretos não haverá problemas emergentes.